# how to specify an item separator in python

Tags: python

I'm working on an assignment and I can't quite figure out how to specify what string I want an item separator to work on.

The line of code is:

```
print('Customer ordered', vCookieOrdered, 'vanilla cookie(s) for the price of $',
  format(vCookieOrderedCost, '.2f'), sep='')
```

I want it to display:

```
"Customer ordered x vanilla cookie(s) for the price of $1.20"
```

but I can't get the separator to only eliminate the space after `$`.

Comment: What output are you seeing?

Comment: Why not just format the whole thing?

Comment: Check out http://pyformat.info. It's a great reference.

Comment: @pault I was seeing "Customer orderedxvanillia cookie(s)..."

Comment: @MadPhysicist I didn't particularly understand how item separators functioned (from my textbook), but I will check out that website. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Quick Solution:

```py
print('Customer ordered {} vanilla cookie(s) for the 
    price of ${}'.format(vCookieOrdered, vCookieOrderedCost))
```

#### Explanation:

I suggest you use `.format` which saves you from having to use the `sep=" "` and give you more control over how to edit your text. Here is an excellent [resource](https://runestone.launchcode.org/runestone/static/thinkcspy/Strings/StringMethods.html) with many interactive examples. `Note: Do a quick search for .format so that you don't have to waste time scrolling through the page`

Answer (score 2):

You need to check how to use '`.format`' method. See some examples. https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#format-examples

```
print('Customer ordered {order:} vanilla cookie(s) for the price of $ {cost:.2f}'.format(order=vCookieOrdered, cost=vCookieOrderedCost))
```

or

```
text = 'Customer ordered {order:} vanilla cookie(s) for the price of $ {cost:.2f}'
print(text.format(order=vCookieOrdered, cost=vCookieOrderedCost))
```